# How do I implement timer with activiti bpmn

Tags: activiti, bpmn

I have a requirement where the a task should wait for a asynchronous request to finish. The process should be verified at regular interval.The activiti workflow should send a request at every 10 min to check if the previous request is being approved.

How do I configure this in activiti BPMN.

Comment: What exactly do you mean that the process should be verified at regular interval? Pls be more specific so that I can eventually extend my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple possibility would be to use a Service Task (http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnJavaServiceTask) to trigger the request and a subsequent Receive Task (http://activiti.org/userguide/#bpmnReceiveTask) waiting to be triggered when the asynchronous response arrives.